# How to call code within Django when new Models are registered

Tags: python, django

I'd like be able to trigger some code to run when a new DB Model is registered in `Django` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`.

**The use case:** I want to add a dynamic global permission on all `Django Models` in my app.

I have this code that works, but I have to schedule it, and I'd rather have it run when new APPS are registered once.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.contrib.auth.models import ContentType, Permission

perms_map = {
    'GET': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
    'OPTIONS': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
    'HEAD': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
    'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
    'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
    'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
    'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
}

def _create_model_view_permissions():
    '''
    Create 'view_(model_name)' Permission for all models.

    Run this when adding a new Model to the DB.
    '''
    for ct in ContentType.objects.all():

        name = 'Can view {}'.format(ct.name)
        codename = 'view_{}'.format(ct.name)

        # create a single instance to be used in all 3 view types
        for i in perms_map.keys():
            if i in ['HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'GET']:
                try:
                    Permission.objects.create(name=name, codename=codename, content_type=ct)
                except IntegrityError:
                    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

New apps/models are registered when your django server process are **reloaded** or **restarted**, so called deploy.

So, why not [write a django custom command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-management-commands/) which calls your `_create_model_view_permissions` function first, then append running this command step to your deploy script?